# Inserting multiple rows into a SQL Server table using a table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, table-variable

I am currently using SQL Server 2008, and I am trying to create a statement using a table variable to insert multiple rows into the table.  As it stands right now, I have to insert the information being added in 4 different spots(2 select statements, 1 insert and 1 update), but would like to be able to create a single table variable, so I only have to enter the information once.  Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example of what I am trying to change.

```
PRINT 'Before'
SELECT  GROUPID, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate
FROM TableXYZ
WHERE groupID in(ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)                                                            

BEGIN TRAN


Insert into TableXYZ
 (GROUPID)
VALUES
 (ID1), (ID2), (ID3), (ID4)                                                             



UPDATE TableXYZ
SET existingdays = 15
    ,ModifiedBy = @userID
    ,ModifiedDate = @today
WHERE groupID in(ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)                                                            


Set  @RowCount =  @@ROWCOUNT 


PRINT 'After '

SELECT  GROUPID, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate
FROM TableXYZ
WHERE groupID in(ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve - why would a single TVP be able to replace two selects, an insert and an update?

Comment: Can you explain your question more detailed?

Comment: If you want to target a table with a variable then AFAIK, you will need to create a (prepared) statement **inside** your query using `CONCAT()` to concat your variable and all other query code.

Comment: This is the existing code that I would like to change

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for in terms of only entering the information once?

```
DECLARE @IDList TABLE
(
    ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @IDList ( ID )
VALUES
     (ID1)
    ,(ID2)
    ,(ID3)
    ,(ID4)

PRINT 'Before'
SELECT  GROUPID, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate
FROM TableXYZ AS T
    INNER JOIN @IDList AS L
        ON T.GroupID = L.ID

BEGIN TRAN


Insert into TableXYZ
 (GROUPID)
SELECT ID
FROM @IDList


UPDATE TableXYZ
SET existingdays = 15
    ,ModifiedBy = @userID
    ,ModifiedDate = @today
FROM TableXYZ AS T
    INNER JOIN @IDList AS L
        ON T.GroupID = L.ID


Set  @RowCount =  @@ROWCOUNT 


PRINT 'After '

SELECT  GROUPID, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate
FROM TableXYZ AS T
    INNER JOIN @IDList AS L
        ON T.GroupID = L.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert into `table1` values from `table2`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

Comment: And of course, here `table2` would have to be a **table variable** and thus it should be `@table2`