# Can't figure out SQL Server Syntax for inserting values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

EDIT:  I may have found the problem.  I was wrong in saying that I'm using SQL-Server 2012.  That's the version of the SSMS I have installed, but apparently the version of the SQL-Server DB is 2005 (SQL Server 9.0.5000), which I found on the look-up table from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185).

I am apparently not understanding how this all works.  Thank you everyone, and sorry for the trouble.

Original Post:

I'm trying to accomplish something very simple, and everywhere I look online gives me syntax which returns an error and won't execute.

This code executes:

```
declare @tester table (col1 varchar(max))

insert into @tester (col1) values ('abc')

select * from @tester
```

But for some reason, when I add more to the values part, I get "Incorrect syntax near ','."

```
declare @tester table (col1 varchar(max))

insert into @tester (col1) values ('abc'), ('dcef')

select * from @tester
```

One reasource online I'm trying to use is this answer:
[Inserting multiple rows into a SQL Server table using a table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323163/inserting-multiple-rows-into-a-sql-server-table-using-a-table-variable)

This modification works, but I can't figure out why I can't figure out my syntax for just a list of values.

```
declare @tester table (col1 varchar(max))

insert into @tester (col1) values ('abc')
insert into @tester (col1) values ('dcef')

select * from @tester
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, and I get the following error.  "There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

Comment: Actually your second code block with "insert into @tester (col1) values ('abc'), ('dcef')" succeeds for me. I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: @DBNull, Thanks.  I'm using  SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2.

Comment: If the server you're running this on is SQL 2008 or later this code should work as there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @jpw, thanks for the response!  The problem is the code doesn't work, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Is that the exact code that's not working?

Comment: Yes.  I just opened a new query in SSMS, pasted the code block in, and pressed the Execute button, and got the exact same error as above ("Incorrect syntax near ','").

Comment: Your code runs fine in SQLFiddle for SQL Server 2012. Maybe you need to reboot!

Comment: Hi.  I think I found the problem.  The version of the DB I'm running is 2005.  I didn't really fully understand where that information was kept, and I finally found it.  Thanks for telling me to look for it, @jpw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `select` to insert many records, and `union all` to have them in a list of literals vs. a selection from another table.

Here's an example:

```
declare @tester table (col1 varchar(max));

insert into @tester (col1) 
   Select 'abc' union all
           'dcef' union all
           'ghi';

select * from @tester;
```

Semicolon delimiters are optional.

Comment: `union all` means insert all values, even if some of the records are duplicates.  If you left it just `union`, and tried to insert two records with `abc` as the data, you'd get just one record (`union` removes duplicates, whereas the `union all` command allows duplicates).